# Python dataframe tranpose a single value from every nth row into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have these alternating rows of times, and I want the times side by side, the Name and Value column are always redundant so the only value I am interested in preserving is the Time column by transposing those values a new column. But I can't quite figure out how to do this gracefully

Before:

|  | Name | Time | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Q | 09:15 | 1 |  |
| 1 | Q | 09:16 | 0 |  |
| 2 | Q | 09:18 | 1 |  |
| 3 | Q | 09:19 | 0 |  |
| 4 | P | 22:30 | 1 |  |
| 5 | P | 23:20 | 0 |  |

After:

|  | Name | Time | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Q | 09:15 | 1 | 09:16 |
| 1 | Q | 09:18 | 1 | 09:19 |
| 2 | P | 23:20 | 1 | 23:20 |

Comment: in the redundant value always 0? is it always one value that is 1 and one that is 0. Or is it possible to have two consecutive 1s? Basically I am asking if there is a possibility to exist Value3 column?

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution that works with your example. In df1 you have the output

```
import pandas as pd


df=pd.DataFrame({
    "Name":["Q"  ,"Q" ,"Q" ,"Q" ,"P" ,"P"],
    "Time":["09:15", "09:16", "09:18", "09:19", "22:30", "23:20"],
    "Value":[1 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,0],
    "Value2":[None,None,None,None,None,None]})

df1=df.loc[df["Value"]!=0]
df2=df.loc[df["Value"]==0]
df2.index=df1.index
df1=df1.drop(columns=["Value2"])

df2=df2.drop(columns=["Name","Value","Value2"])
df2=df2.rename(columns={"Time":"Value2"})

df1=df1.join(df2)
```